# Character Array Java

Tags: java, arrays, char

This question is hard to be asked on Google even though is so simple. 
Basically I wrote this :

```
      public static void main(String[] args) {
         char cipher[] = {'a','b','c','c','d','t','w'};
           System.out.println(cipher[0]+cipher[2]);
          }
 }
```

and the println result was : 196 instead of ac. Of course when I did

```
 System.out.println(cipher[0]+""+cipher[2]);
```

It showed me ac as intended. 
So my question is just what is this 196 ? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So my question is just what is this 196 ?

It's the UTF-16 code unit for 'a' (which is 97) followed by the UTF-16 code unit for 'c' (which is 99).

Other than for string concatenation, operands of the addition operator undergo binary numeric promotion ([JLS 5.6.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2)) so you're actually performing addition of `int` values. Your code is equivalent to:

```
System.out.println((int) cipher[0] + (int) cipher[2]);
```

Comment: Beat me by 10 seconds. Anyways... I'm not too disappointed of being beaten by a 617k guy ;)

Comment: +1 a `char` is an unsigned 16-bit integer and when you add two of them together with `+` you get an `int` type value.

Comment: @Izmaki a 617k guy !? do you mean there is more than one ;)

Answer (score 0):

196 is the ASCII value of 'a' + the ASCII value of 'c'.

When you add `char`s together, without any other hints, Java interprets them as numbers.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, a `char` is essentially an unsigned 16-bit integer with their integer value corresponding to their Unicode value. 196 is the sum of the integer representations of 'a' ja 'c'.

Answer (score 0):

The result 196 is the ASCII value de 'a' (ASCII 97) + 'c' (ASCII 99).